# É possível utilizar elipses com Flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

Tenho um card de largura variável (no exemplo deixei fixo) com um texto alinhado a esquerda e um botão alinhado a direita na mesma linha, queria que o texto ocupasse toda a largura disponível em uma única linha e, se ultrapassar o máximo, cortar com elipses

Consigo organizar o conteúdo da forma que quero com flexbox ou aplicar o efeito de elipses, porém não consigo fazer ambos juntos:

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  background: green;
}

.card > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card > div > div > span {
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <p>MAIS CONTEÚDO</p>

  <div>
    <div>
      <span>título</span>

      <span>subtítulo</span>
    </div>

    <button>X</button>
  </div>

  <p>MAIS CONTEÚDO</p>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <p>MAIS CONTEÚDO</p>

  <div>
    <div>
      <span>texto texto texto texto texto</span>

      <span>subtítulo</span>
    </div>

    <button>X</button>
  </div>

  <p>MAIS CONTEÚDO</p>
</div>
```

É possível fazer isso sem JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema nesse seu exemplo é que a div por fora do span possui `overflow: visible`. Se forçar que o conteúdo não vaze dessa div, o `text-overflow` do span interno será respeitado:

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  background: green;
}

.card > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card > div > div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card > div > div > span {
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <p>MAIS CONTEÚDO</p>

  <div>
    <div>
      <span>título</span>

      <span>subtítulo</span>
    </div>

    <button>X</button>
  </div>

  <p>MAIS CONTEÚDO</p>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <p>MAIS CONTEÚDO</p>

  <div>
    <div>
      <span>texto texto texto texto texto</span>

      <span>subtítulo</span>
    </div>

    <button>X</button>
  </div>

  <p>MAIS CONTEÚDO</p>
</div>
```